# Is it possible to have an space in a resource key and use it on ASPX page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a resource that a key will have a space, like

```
My key | Some string
```

In my aspx page I want to call

```
<%$ Resource:Resources, My Key %>
```

Is there some syntax that allows me to use "My Key" instead of "MyKey"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>No. The key for a resource setting may not contain spaces. Resource files are compiled so that the keys become variable names. This would be the equivalent of saying:</strike>

```
int My int;
```

This just is not allowed.

I take it back. Having applied some tests, this can be done and basically as you have described it. Some things that I see off the top is that in a web site, the resources file can't be in the `App_GlobalResources` folder it needs to be in `App_LocalResources`. I named my resources file the same as my page name like: `Default.aspx.resx`. Resources in the `App_GlobalResources` folder are set at internal scope automatically.

Inside it I had 2 keys and 2 values set:

```
ThisKey | ThisValue
My Key | My Value
```

To acess them from a control in the webpage I used a hyperlink control to test it:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlLink" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources: ThisKey%>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Which output a link with the text `ThisValue`. And also:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlLink" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources: My Key %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Which output a link with the text 'My Value'. I did notice that if I attempted to specify the "class" parameter by using `Resources: Default.aspx, My Key` it bombed. It was only successful using the resources within the `App_LocalResources` folder and only when specified to that file name.

I'm sure this isn't the only way to do this, but this method was successful in allowing a space in the key name for that page.

Comment: I am not generating any code. I am using "No code generation" in the resx file.

Comment: @BrunoLM: That's irrelevant. The rules governing resource files are the same whether you're actually generating code or not.

Comment: the rules are *not* the same. When you don't generate a code for the resx file you can have string with spaces as keys and you can very well retrieve the values with a custom resource provider.

Comment: @BrunoLM: After some testing I have posted an update, striking errant information and adding a method for how I achieved the result from within a webpage.